# Obtaining authorization token from Azure AD with Dotnetopenauth

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, access-token, dotnetopenauth, azure-active-directory

I am trying to obtain authorization token from Azure AD through DotNetOpenAuth library. I do not want to use ADAL because I have a huge project in .net 3.5 and ADAL does not supports .net 3.5 (only .net > 4). However, I can't quite get it to work with Azure AD. I do not know what to configure. So far, this is what I have:

```
    private static WebServerClient _webServerClient;
    private static string _accessToken;
    // Client ID (as obtained from Azure AD portal)
    private static string clientId = "here goes my client id guid";
    // Client Secret (as obtained from Azure AD portal)
    private static string appKey = "here goes my secret";
    private static string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    private static string tenant = "mytenant.domain.com";
    private static string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
    // Azure AD resource I am trying to access
    private static string serviceResourceId = "https://mytenant.domain.com/protectedresource";


    private static void InitializeWebServerClient()
    {
        var authorizationServer = new AuthorizationServerDescription
        {
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(""/* WHAT TO PUT HERE */),
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri(""/* WHAT TO PUT HERE */)
        };
        _webServerClient = new WebServerClient(authorizationServer, clientId, appKey);
    }



    private static void RequestToken()
    {
        var state = _webServerClient.GetClientAccessToken();
        _accessToken = state.AccessToken;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        InitializeWebServerClient();
        RequestToken();
    }
```

The problem is I do not know what to place here. I do not know what values I should place here:

AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(""**/* WHAT TO PUT HERE */**),

TokenEndpoint = new Uri(""**/* WHAT TO PUT HERE */**)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this **GitHub sample** assists you with authentication. It has 3 methods for authenticating and acquiring authentication token with detailed instructions. Check the app.config for sample values and method comments for details on what is required.

Link to the sample: [Azure Authentication GitHub Sample](https://github.com/HarvestingClouds/AzureAuthentication)

Related blog for the sample: [Azure Authentication - Authenticating any Azure API Request in your Application](http://harvestingclouds.com/post/azure-authentication-authenticating-any-azure-api-request-in-your-application/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the two endpoints you want are:

```
https://login.windows.net/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/authorize
https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}/oauth2/token
```

Where `{tenantId}` is your tenant's GUID identifier. It may also work with your domain as well, but I haven't checked that.